# I am having a problem with mobaXterm. The program below keep receiving the error:

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mobaxterm

```
Error:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note:
I know main is correct. I also use the command `g++ -c project_3.cpp`
and this does what it should do and that is not have text below. I get the error when typing `g++ -o project_3.exe project_3.o`.

Code:

```
#include <algorithm> // function collection.

#include <iostream> // function collection.

#include <string> // function collection.

using namespace std; // access to functions cin & cout.

int main() // Starting for a return integer.
{
    string first_name; // Variable name *String type*.
    cout << "Please enter your first name: "; // User input.
    cin >> first_name; // Variable with user input.

    string last_name; // Variable name *String type*.
    cout << "Please enter your last name: "; // User input.
    cin >> last_name; // Variable with user input.

    string word_1; // Variable name *String type*.
    cout << "Please enter a word:"; // User input.
    cin >> word_1; // Variable with user input.

    string word_2; // Variable name *String type*.
    cout << "Please enter a word:"; // User input.
    cin >> word_2; // Variable with user input.

    string word_3; // Variable name *String type*.
    cout << "Please enter a word:"; // User input.
    cin >> word_3; // Variable with user input.

    string rand_comp = first_name+last_name+word_1+word_2+word_3; // Merges user input.

    random_shuffle(rand_comp.begin(), rand_comp.end()); // Randomizes user input.

    cout << rand_comp<< '\n'; // Outputs accumulated data.
return 0; // End of 1st (and only) int main.
}
```

Comment: Moba X-Term is a terminal program with an X-Windows client built in. It's a tool you use to access a remove server. It has nothing to do with your programming problem.

Comment: What is the outcome with `g++ project_3.cpp -o project_3.exe`? to build and link all in one shot?

Comment: In linux  you don't need or want the `.exe` extension. Your problem is definitely not related to your choice of terminal software.

Comment: Does a simple `int main() { }` work?